# Does textures drawn with glDrawTexfOES are affected by lights?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, light

currently, I use glDrawArrays to render texture in simple quads. I hope increase framerate by using glDrawTexfOES instead (all my sprites have the same z position).
Before doing this work I would like to know if these textures will still be affected by my 3d lights.

Comment: What do you mean by "affected"? Rendering wise? Performance wise?

Comment: I talk about rendering. I would like to know if glDrawTexfOES will take care about my lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard OpenGL ES lighting happens at the vertex level, glDrawTexfOES bypasses the vertex pipeline completely. So no, lighting won't happen on glDrawTexf rectangles.